# When can I usefully delete my comment?

Tags: support

On occasion there is a comment thread (three or four comments and responses) that result in a useful clarification of a Question or Answer. Once the question has been amended the comments are no longer required and can be deleted.

Thinking now about the last response on such a comment thread. If that comment is deleted, will the person to whom is was addressed be able to read it? Or for all intents and purposes will it have disappeared without necessarily being read?

Example:

- Answer: Use `some_command and its arguments` to fix the problem
- Comment from roaima: Can you explain why, please
- Comment: @roaima it's because of *foo bar* interacting with the widget
- Comment from roaima: Ah, great. Could you add that into your answer please
- Comment: @roaima it's done

At this point the comments can be deleted. The last comment is there solely to flag the change to me (roaima) so I get an inbox notification.

So, at what point can that last comment be deleted, knowing that I (roaima) will be able to read the comment?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you talking about comments you posted? If your comment has been acted upon by its intended recipient (the details added to the question), you know it has been read and can be safely deleted. No, the recipient will no longer be able to read it but there's no need to, it's already been read. I'm not sure what situations you're describing here.

Comment: @terdon a situation where you don't know the OP has read the comment (and there's no obvious reaction from which to infer this)

Comment: OK, then it's up to you. Yes, if you delete your comment it's gone and the notification is removed from the OP's inbox. Is that what the main question is?

Comment: @terdon yes that's what I was trying to ask (clearly not very successfully). And "oh". Thank you

Comment: @terdon. So if I delete my immediately preceding comment you might not ever get to read it. And there's no action for you in it so I have no way of knowing when or if you've read it.